# testing field type a model in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, model, mongoid

i use ruby on rails. also i use minitest framework for testing and mongoid for database. i want to write a model test. my model is below:

```
class Identity
  include Mongoid::Document
  include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid

  field :name
  field :email
  field :password_digest

  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

the model test is:

```
describe Identity do
  it "must include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid" do
    Identity.must_include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid
  end

  it "should have name" do
    Identity.new.must_respond_to :name
  end

  it "should have email" do
    Identity.new.must_respond_to :email
  end

  it "should have password_digest" do
    Identity.new.must_respond_to :password_digest
  end

   it "should type of String" do
    Identity.new.name.type.must_equal "String"
  end
end
```

my problem is about testing the field's type

```
it "should type of String" do
  Identity.new.name.type.must_equal "String"
end
```

How can i test a field's type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you need something like `Identity.new.name.is_a? String`?

Comment: too basd you don't use rspec: https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tip - while not an answer to your actual question, it is usually not that 
wise test implementation details of code, because it is more likely 
to change, and if you think of system validation through tests, it is not that important
*how* it is implemented, but *what it does*, eg. *how it behaves*.

A canonical example is that of testing functionality of a Stack class. Instead of 
pushing and popping items out of stack and checking the size, it is likely better to 
just push and pop things, and see that if you pop an empty stack, you get appropriate
exception. And naturally you want to check that items are returned in last in, first out
(LIFO) order.

So, in your case, instead of testing what kind of type your field `name` is, rather
test what you *do* with the name.